# BAASBox cross domain

Tags: unity-game-engine, cross-domain, baasbox

I'm using BAASBox for the back-end to my Unity3D application. The Unity player implements a security model that restricts accessing data on a domain other than the one hosting the .unity3d file. To make everything work i need to add a crossdomain.xml file to allow my Unity application to access the BASSBox server but i'm not sure where to place this file.

Comment: A workaround that seems to mostly work is to add a proxy within a virtual host. Adding `ProxyPass /baasbox http://localhost:9000` works allowing Unity WWW access to `localhost:80/baasbox` URL and then the proxy rule forwards to port 9000. ProxyPassReverse is also required.

Comment: The above avoids having to have a crossdomain file as the ports match.